# Change SharePoint 2013 sub-site color programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, master-pages, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-object-model

I have a main site collection that is using the stock Publishing Site template in red. All sub-sites are inheriting the master page and theme. All sub-sites are using the Project Site template. I am creating these using the Server Object Model. All the sub-sites are the standard blue after creation. How can I force them to be red?

```
static void SetupNewSubSite(int currentYear, SPItemEventProperties properties, int siteIndexId)
{
    string description = properties.AfterProperties["Project_x0020_Description"].ToString();
    SPListItem CurrentItem = properties.ListItem;
    String subSiteUrl = Convert.ToString(siteIndexId);
    SPSite projectSiteCollection = new SPSite(properties.Web.Site.Url + "/" + currentYear);           
    SPWeb sWeb = new SPSite(properties.SiteId).OpenWeb(properties.RelativeWebUrl);            
    SPWeb oWeb = projectSiteCollection.RootWeb;
    SPWebCollection cWebs = oWeb.Webs;
    SPWeb xWeb = cWebs.Add(subSiteUrl, properties.AfterProperties["Title"].ToString(),
    properties.AfterProperties["Project_x0020_Description"].ToString(), 1033, "{B5B6BDD1-485A-44BC-B093-F1048271C49D}", false, false);
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but you are using the SPWebCollection.Add() method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms412285.aspx. This expects a SPWebTemplate, not a GUID. You say "they are standard blue" - if they inherit the MasterPage, they should have the color of your root web? Or are they not really inheriting? Maybe you just have to inherit upon creation of the web?

Comment: @moontear Thanks for the link. You can customize a site and save it as a template. Then you have to use the GUID because it no longer has a standard name. The root web is red, the sites that are spawned are blue. If I go in to site settings on the spawned site and click "Change Look" it says "inheriting from parent", which is the root web.

Comment: One other tidbit. If I go in to the root web site settings and go to Master Page, I can click the check boxes that say "Reset all subsites to inherit this site master page setting". Then all the subsites turn red.

Comment: Very good information. Since you are using code to provision the sites, it would be easy doing what solves your problem by code: Resetting the subsites to inherit. Could you check that after creating a new site and you stop inheriting the masterpage from the root web, then inherit again (change back and forth) - is it still blue or would that make it red as well?

Comment: How do you stop inheriting, then inherit with C#? I tried forcing usage of the parent master page on the new web. It didn't do anything.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8151/sp2010-reset-all-subsites-to-inherit-masterpage-using-c